# How to access the flash messages in android mobile?

Tags: android

I am trying to access the flash messages but not getting any idea, any method for that to access those flash messages.
If you have any idea, give it to me.

Comment: What are "flash messages" in the context of Android? I have never heard of any Android feature being referred to as "flash messages."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Flash messages are those when we use any ussd codes like *111#, then will get reply message popup on the screen which will be not stored in inbox. I need to access that message's content and can store it in the textbox on the form... I think now you got the prob. definition.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)?

Comment: @SantoshParashetti did you ever find a solution to this? If so, please share.